# Homotheties and the Set of Centroids

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

This exercise is particularly puzzling for me and I cannot seem to get anywhere with it.  I am expected to solve this problem by implementing homotheties to circles.  The problem states:

Let *A* and *B* be distinct points of a circle *o*.  What is the set of possible centroids of triangles *ABC* with *C* belonging to *o*? Recall that the centroid of a triangle is the intersection point of the medians.

All advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $D$ be the midpoint of $AB$, and $G$ the centroid of $\triangle ABC$. Then $G \in CD$ and  $\frac{DG}{DC}=\frac{1}{3}$, so the locus of $G$ is homothetic to the locus of$C$.

Comment: Perhaps I am just not following your Hint properly, but if *D* lies on *AB* and *G* is the centroid, then wouldn't *G* $\in$ *CD*, because the only median passing through *D* is from vertex *C*.  Should the labels *A* and *C* be interchanged in your Hint?

Comment: @Nelly Right, thanks for catching that. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Thanks! Your Hint completely helped me solve this exercise.